# Magento 2 : call product assigned attribute info in static block

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-view, additional-information

I have a static block position in my product detail page.
what i want to do is call the content inside more information tab data of attributes to show in that static block.
any help would be great
waiting for your replies
this is magento2 i am referring to

**explanation** if this helps - i am trying to move this data of attributes info http://awesomescreenshot.com/0b2639uq25 to a static block on product view page , static block already exists just need to call this tab information in static block

Comment: explanation if this helps - i am trying to move this data of attributes info http://awesomescreenshot.com/0b2639uq25 to a static block on product view page , static block already exists just need to call this tab information in static block

Answer (score 0):

$_product = $block->getProduct();
$CMS-BLOCK-NAME = $_product->getAttributeText('ATTRIBUTE-NAME');
if ($CMS-BLOCK-NAME):
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId($CMS-BLOCK-NAME )->toHtml();
endif;

try the above, put in your \app\design\frontend\THEME NAME.....\templates\product\VIEW.PHTML Edit and replace CMS-BLOCK-NAME and ATTRIBUTE-NAME and enter yours